# Error 404 when running sample Spring MVC using Spring STS

Tags: java, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, cloud-foundry

I tried running a sample Spring MVC using Spring STS in Eclipse, however when I try to run it on CloudFoundry using my account, when I access the  "Mapped URL" I get Error 404

Which should at least show "Hello World" and show the server time.

I wonder why its not running? I don't see any error in the console.

EDIT: This is the complete  [console log.](http://pastebin.com/q1zVEmiq)

Comment: No error? Strange, try using the VMC tool instead of the STS plugin, you might get more info with vmc logs.
http://start.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/installing-vmc.html
http://start.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/vmc-quick-ref.html

Comment: Based on the video tutorial, Spring-from-Zero-to-Cloud-In-60-minutes part one, just using the Eclipse and STS it is able to run on the cloudfoundry hosting

Comment: It's just an idea to get more info on what's going on. Without a stacktrace or a piece of code it's gonna be hard to help you.

Comment: @xybrek - without more information, like error logs, it's impossible to divine what your problem might be.

Comment: I think the problem is with the mapping: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' however in the HomeController there's a mapping: @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is not detected, i think you forgot to configure spring to scan your application for annotation based controller with :

```
   <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage.com...."/>
   <context:annotation-config/>
```

http://renidev.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/how-to-use-springs-context-component-scan-and-annotation/